# Create and Save file in JS ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I am developing a Chrome extension, so I use JS, to get some data out of our ERP-System and to convert that into a xml.
So fare I get the data out of the ERP-System but now I can not save the data to the local computer.

For better understanding I show you my code with changed URL for the api request.

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) =>{
    let requestUrl = 'https://url'
    async function getResponse(){

        const response = await fetch(requestUrl)
        return await response.json()
    }

    getDeliveryResponse().then(delivery => {
        json_to_xml(delivery)
    })
```

```
function json_to_xml (jsonFile){
    let xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>'

    const fs = require('fs')

    fs.writeFile("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop", xml_data, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err)
        }
        console.log("The file was saved")
    })
```

The code above gives me the following error "Uncaught (in promise) `ReferenceError: require is not defined"` in the line of `const fs = require('fs')`.

I have searched the qeb for a while and haven't found something to work. I hope someone can help me.

### Edit 1

I am new to JS and server workers.
The plugin should be easy and simple to use. I am happy with every suggestion for the filesave.

### Edit 2

I have done a check. My code is running in a **non-browser environment**.
So I have tried the `const link = document.createElement("a").` thing. Unfortunately because of the non-browser environment it is not working.

Please can someone help me.

Comment: service-workers needed to set the browser strategy for caching your application. Service-worker run in browser and *require* is function from *node*. The is no *node* functions in browser.

Comment: You have to import `fs`

Comment: Ok. Can you give me a example code?

Comment: So what should I do than?

Comment: you can save your data somewhere in these browser storages.
Maybe [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Depends on the problem you need to solve

Comment: Extensions can't do it like this. You'll need to use an [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) where you will trigger a download of the blob data via `<a>` DOM element with a `download=filename` attribute and the data will be written to a file inside the browser's directory for downloads. If you really want to write to an arbitrary file you can use the new File System Access API or write a separate utility and call it via nativeMessaging API.

Comment: As I sayed, I need to get an xml file in the end, that is stored an the local computer

Comment: The is a [new feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) to file system access by browser. I don't use it yet. And it doesn't have much browser support

Comment: Need to write to a file without UI?

Comment: With or without, it is not written down. If there is a way to use UI, for example to choose save location, then it would be greate. Or wht do you meen?

Comment: Unfortunately the code is running in a non-browser environment. So the file system API is not working